# Linked list questions in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I first tried to create a node but I am not sure if it is correct. I am sorry that I am new to C++. I am not sure how to let my node `p` to point at the first element of the linked list. Hope help would be offered. Thanks

Here is my function:

```
template<class Type>
void longestSequence(linkedListType<Type>& list, int& maxCount, Type& value)
{
    nodeType<Type> *p = first;
    int count = 0;
    int tempValue = 0;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->info == p->link->info)
        {
            count++;
            tempValue = p->info;
        } 
        p = p->link;
    } 
    if(count > maxCount)
    {
        maxCount = count;
        value = tempValue;
    }
    else if(count == maxCount && tempValue < value)
    {
        value = tempValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to check that both `p` and `p->info` is not null, also, you should probably check that those values actually matches the `value`?

Comment: thanks for your advice first.  i will try to amend the code.  However, the compiler keeps showing the error that 'first' is not a declared identifier and i dont know how to solve it

Comment: "I am sorry that I am new to C++" - That's no reason to apologize for anything. Just keep learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `linkedListType<Type>` should have a member  `nodeType<Type>* head`.
When you create the first node of the linked list, you should assign its address to `head`.

Then you can access the first node of the linked list whenever you want.
For eg, `nodeType<Type> *p = list.head`

Comment: thanks for your answer first.  there is a protected nodeType<Type> *first.  but when i tried to access it by typing "nodeType<Type> *p = list.first", the compiler said that i cant access protected variable

Comment: you have 2 options: `1.` Make the member public. Then you can access it. `2.` Make the member private and define a getter function to access it.

Comment: i am sorry that i can only work on this particular function instead of adding new member function or changing the header file.

Comment: If you cannot change the access specifier, you cannot access the variable. The protected member can be accessed from a derived class. You have to create a derived class and make your function member of the derived class. Why can't you change the header file?